# Windows Authentication in .net Core Razor Pages App

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-authentication

```html
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50490",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication4": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

web.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <aspNetCore forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I created a .Net Core Razor Pages App. I want to use Windows Authentication. I think that
i made all Configuration but does not work. I can not find where is the Problem.

Program.cs

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseIISIntegration();
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

launchSettings.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTTXI.png)

I enter username and Password but does not work. What should i do?

Comment: Do you enable Windows Authentication on IIS?

Comment: I have launchSettings.json file.

Comment: I guess IIS is configured with `Web.config` file

Comment: I have web.config.

Comment: I work in debug mode. Because of this i think IIS configuretion is not important, isnt it?

Comment: If you debug on IIS, `Web.config` is important. You need to disable anonymous authentication and enable windows authentication on your project. (Right-click the project in `Solution Explorer` and select `Properties` -> Select the `Debug` tab -> Clear the check box for `Enable Anonymous Authentication` -> Select the check box for `Enable Windows Authentication` -> Save and close the property page)

Comment: can you also show us your `launchSettings.json`

Comment: I made "Right-click the project in Solution Explorer ....." but doesnt work.

Comment: i added "launchSettings.json "  but as a Image. You can see

Comment: No, I can't. My corporate firewall blocks all images on stackoverflow.

Comment: I added launchSettings.json